# Provide element name for Xml Serialization Error

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, xml-serialization

I'm trying to figure out how I can provide a custom error message or at least specify the element name for an XML post to my Web API.  Currently, the model state error that I'm getting is

> There is an error in XML document (2, 4).

The inner exception of this error provides a little more information with:

> The string 'false fds' is not a valid Boolean value.

I would like to be able to return something more specific to the user that states the element that contains the invalid value vs having them search through their XML to determine where that value exists.

Here is the XML that I'm posting:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<checkin>
    <checkinType>1</checkinType>
    <server>server1</server>
    <notes>New Checkin</notes>
    <productCheckins>
        <ihsCheckin>
            <vendor>IBM</vendor>
            <make>HTTP Server</make>
            <model></model>
            <version>8.5.5.0</version>
            <installLocation>/opt/IBM</installLocation>
            <is64Bit>false fds</is64Bit>
        </ihsCheckin>
</productCheckins>
</checkin>
```

Here is are the classes that I'm trying to convert to:

```
[XmlRoot("checkin")]
public class Checkin
{
    [XmlElement("checkinTime")]
    public DateTime CheckinTime { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("checkType")]
    public int CheckinType { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("notes")]
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("server")]
    public string Server { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("productCheckins")]
    [XmlArrayItem("wasCheckin", typeof(WASCheckin))]
    [XmlArrayItem("ihsCheckin", typeof(IHSCheckin))]
    public List<ProductCheckin> ProductCheckins { get; set; }
}

public class ProductCheckin
{
    [XmlElement("vendor")]
    public string Vendor { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("make")]
    public string Make { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("model")]
    public string Model { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("installLocation")]
    public string InstallLocation { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("is64Bit")]
    public bool Is64Bit { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, I just want to say, the error is related to the is64Bit element but I haven't seen a way to do that yet short of parsing the XML manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I kinda have to agree with it:

```
<is64Bit>false fds</is64Bit>
```

is not a valid value for:

```
[XmlElement("is64Bit")]
public bool Is64Bit { get; set; }
```

You could treat it as a `string`:

```
[XmlElement("is64Bit")]
public string Is64Bit { get; set; }
```

and handle it separately afterwards.

Comment: That might not have been the best example.  I'm just looking for a way to provide more detailed errors back to the user.  Another scenario might be where the user spells one of the elements wrong or passes an element that doesn't exist.  I know they can validate on their side, but I'd like to be able to provide as much information that I can back to the user too.  Would implementing my own serializer be a better option to achieve this?

Comment: @JStinebaugh an xsd-validating xml-reader is available in the framework and gives detailed output. I would run it via that.